# Proof verification |A∪B| ≤ n + m

Tags: formal-languages

I'm rather new to formal languages and reading up on Peter Linz's *An Introduction to FORMAL LANGUAGES and AUTOMATA*. As an exercise in the pre-requisite chapter, there's a proof. I'm not so familiar with formal proofs so I would like someone to tell me:

- Does it prove it?
- How would you make this proof stronger? I am not interested so much in seeing an alternative way to prove this (assuming mine is good) - I would rather know how I can make my proofs better in the future.

PROOF:

```
|A∪B| ≤ n + m
n = |A|, m = |B|
```

Where A & B are sets. So if I understand correctly, I want to prove that the size of the union of A & B is smaller or equal to the sum of the individual sizes of A & B. Which intuitively makes lots of sense to me.

```
|A∪B| ≤ n + m
|A∪B| ≤ |A| + |B|
```

I then try to express the right-hand side differently. If I draw it, I can see that the following holds true (U for universal set, sorry still working out those symbols):

```
|A| + |B| = |U| - |A| + |A∩B| + |U| - |B| + |A∩B|
|A| + |B| = 2|U| - |A| - |B|  + 2|A∩B| (1)
```

And also

```
|A∪B|  = |U| - |A| - |B| + 2|A∩B| (2)
```

If I substitute back into the initial equation:

```
|A∪B| ≤ |A| + |B|
|U| - |A| - |B| + 2|A∩B| ≤ 2|U| - |A| - |B|  + 2|A∩B|
|U| ≤ 2|U|
```

Which is always true.

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no specific question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Having said that, what you've posted doesn't prove anything. You've assumed the thing you're trying to prove (in your last grey box) and shown that some true thing follows from it, but that establishes nothing. For example, here is a "proof" that I am the pope. Suppose that I am the pope. That would imply that the pope is a man. Well, the pope _is_ a man, so I must be the pope.

Comment: What do you mean by "make this proof stronger"? Either it is a proof, or it is not.

Comment: A proof can be made stronger if we remove mistakes from it. Anyhow, not in scope as this is just math and belong to math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more streamlined version of your proof.

Notice first that
$$
A \cup B = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B), \\
A = (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B), \\
B = (B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B).
$$
All these decompositions are into disjoint sets, and so
$$
|A \cup B| = |A \setminus B| + |B \setminus A| + |A \cap B|
|A| = |A \setminus B| + |A \cap B|, \\
|B| = |B \setminus A| + |A \cap B|.
$$
A bit of algebra shows that
$$
 |A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|.
$$
Given this, $|A \cap B| \geq 0$ implies the desired result, $|A \cup B| \leq |A| + |B|$.

Answer (score 1):

A similar, shorter, proof relies on the *inclusion/exclusion principle*, namely if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then
$$
|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|
$$
(If you're not familiar with this identity, look at a small Venn diagram.) So we can conclude
$$
|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B| \le |A| + |B|
$$